# Center a drawn string relative to the window size?

Tags: java, string, center

I'm trying to center a string drawn with a ""system", Font.BOLD, 90" font in Java. I've tried (width/2 - (font.size/2 * num_of_chars)) but that didn't work.

```
g2d.setFont(new Font("system", Font.BOLD, 90));
g2d.drawString("Pause", (int) ((800/2) - ((Font.getSize()/2) * 5)),270);
```

Comment: Please add sample code or clarify your question - are you drawing on an AWT object, for instance? What about it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`getFontMetrics()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getFontMetrics()).[`getStringBounds(String, Graphics)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to get the bounds of the string with the current font.

So it would look something like this:

```
g2d.setFont(new Font("system", Font.BOLD, 90));
String msg = "Pause";
Rectangle2D bounds = g2d.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(msg, g2d);
g2d.drawString(msg, (int) ((getWidth() + bounds.getWidth()) / 2), 270);
```

Comment: Is there a way to get getStringBounds() to return a rect instead of a rect2D?

Comment: edit: nevermind. I see that 2D has a getWidth method too. Thanks.